# get products by id in asp.net?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

**my problem is:** how to get product by ProductCategoryID?

[image]

Comment: didn't your sp get the products by Id mate?

Comment: Why not use a simple sql query like `Select * from products where productCategoryId = <the selected Category ID>`

Comment: yes that's simple enough as including the @ID at the end mate, not sure if he did so yet?

Comment: Its still vague if you  are asking if that works or is it giving you error Mate?

Comment: None of your categories shown in the snapshot are "Hardware". If that's all you have in the table then it's logical you don't get any results back. The query that takes the Category ID should definitely work AS LONG AS the Languages table has an entry for the passed Language as well. Did you check that?

Comment: how can i use ur query?  Select * from products where productCategoryId = <the selected Category ID> ??

Comment: @Shqiptar just update the sp with that query, did you even add the `@ID` to where clause like you were talking in question?

Comment: i got error: Incorrect syntax near '<'.

Comment: This question deserves to be closed, as this problem is literally unsolvable or too trivial. Without concrete code, there is nothing we can do.

Answer (score 1):

First pass 'Hardware' category Id to click function and then Use that in your Sql statement as parameter.
In Sql statement-

```
Select * from Products where ProductCategoryID=@PassedCategoryID
```

[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELCkL.jpg)